# NameError when running python code

Tags: python, xlwt

I am Getting a NameError when running the code below. How can I resolve this?

Code:

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Status')

passed = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: back_color green')
failed = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: back_color red')


color = (passed if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed'] else
    (failed if passorfail in ['fail','Failed','failed'] else xlwt.easyxf()))

worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3,passorfail, style = color)

workbook.save('passfail2.xls')
print "Completed"
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\airspan_eclipse\Excel_Gen\passfail2.py", line 9, in <module>
    color = (passed if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed'] else
NameError: name 'passorfail' is not defined
```

Expected Result:

The Excel cell color will be changed based on the text, if pass/Pass/passed/Passed means green and fail/Fail/failed/Failed means red respectively.

Comment: Well you haven't defined `passorfail` anywhere. Is it meant to be a string?

Comment: @Haidro : The passorfail value will get from another file and it will be a string(Pass/Fail).But I have n number of test cases and corresponding passorfail status.How to modify this code and works well with n number of test cases

Answer (score 2):

`passorfail` is not defined. Plus, you are trying to set cell background color incorrectly.

Here's the code with fixes(`passorfail` is read from `raw_input()`):

```
import xlwt

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    passorfail = f.read()

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Status')

style = xlwt.easyxf()
pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN

if passorfail in ['pass', 'Passed', 'passed']:
    pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['green']
elif passorfail in ['fail', 'Failed', 'failed']:
    pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map['red']

style.pattern = pattern
worksheet.write_merge(6, 6, 3, 3, passorfail, style=style)

workbook.save('passfail2.xls')
print "Completed"
```

EDIT:

Here's the code for generating report from test results dictionary:

```
import xlwt


def generate_styles(colours):
    styles = {}
    for colour in colours:
        style = xlwt.easyxf()

        pattern = xlwt.Pattern()
        pattern.pattern = xlwt.Pattern.SOLID_PATTERN
        pattern.pattern_fore_colour = xlwt.Style.colour_map[colour]
        style.pattern = pattern

        styles[colour] = style
    return styles


def generate_report(results, name):
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('Status')

    styles = generate_styles(['green', 'red'])

    # write headers
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Test Name')
    worksheet.write(0, 1, 'Test Result')

    # write test results
    row = 1
    for test_name, test_result in results.iteritems():
        if test_result in ['pass', 'Passed', 'passed']:
            style = styles['green']
        elif test_result in ['fail', 'Failed', 'failed']:
            style = styles['red']
        else:
            style = None

        worksheet.write(row, 0, test_name, style=style)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, test_result, style=style)
        row += 1

    workbook.save(name)


# assuming test results is a dictionary
results = {'TC01': 'passed', 'TC02': 'failed', 'TC03': 'pass'}
generate_report(results, 'report.xls')
print "Completed"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The above code works well . But I have to get "passorfail" value from another file. And I have "n" number of test cases (like TC01-Pass,TC02-Fail etc). For "n" number of cases how will modify this code.

Comment: Modified the code to read `passorfail` from another file. You mean that you have "pass" of "fail" on each line in the input file? Please clarify what do you mean by "n" cases. Thanks.

Comment: The main python script has test cases like TC01,TC02..etc.When executing test cases it will print "TC01-Passed" and "TC02-Failed" like that.From this main file using regexp will store TC01,Passed,TC-02,Failed to variables(like a = TC01,Status1 = Passed).From these variables we have to generate excel sheet with test case number and test case status respectively with background color(Green/Red based on status).

Comment: If I understand you correctly this excel file generation should be a function with one argument that will be a dictionary in format like {'TC01': 'passed', 'TC02': 'failed'}. And in the excel file you want to have two columns: 'Test Case Name' and 'Result', 'Result' cells should be with an appropriate background. Please confirm and I'll edit the code for it.

Comment: Yes alecxe You'r right.Excel having two columns with test case name and result.Test cases results will vary . And I have to give background colors based on the results (Passed - Green and Failed -Red).Please edit the code.

Comment: Added the code for generating xls report from test results dictionary.

Comment: Hi alecxe am getting this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\airspan_eclipse\Excel_Gen\reportgen.py", line 29, in <module>
    for test_name, test_result in results.iteritems():
NameError: name 'results' is not defined

Comment: Hm, I've copied and ran the code as is - it works for me without any errors.

Comment: Now i copied the code in notepad and ran.It works for me.Previously I tried with Eclipse(might be alignment problem). Thanks a lot alecxe for your great effort and good time.

Answer (score 0):

That if/else line is horrible. Write it out in full and you'll see what the problem is.

```
if passorfail in ['pass','Passed','passed']:
    color = passed
elif passorfail in ['fail','Failed','failed']:
    color = failed
else:
    color = xlwt.easyxf()
```

Now it's obvious that you're referring to `passorfail`, but you haven't defined it.